# Plotting in Pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to Pyplot and simply trying to read data from a .csv file and produce a line plot using ax.plot(x,y):

```
filepath ='Monthly_Raw_Financials.csv'
raw_data = pd.`read_csv`(filepath, index_col='Month', parse_dates=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(raw_data.index, raw_data['Profit'])
plt.show()
```

I get only an empty axis with no data plotted and and error message "'Series' object has no attribute 'find'".  I am following the example of a number of tutorials.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the entire code, it is not a snip.  "find' is not used anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps try plotting the column values instead, i.e. `raw_data['Profit'].values`

Comment: Except for the two import statementsfrom matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, a column is a Series object, which isn't quite the same as a numpy array. It holds a numpy array in its `.values` attribute, but it also holds an index (`.index` attribute). I don't understand where your error comes from, but you could try plotting the values instead, i.e.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(raw_data.index, raw_data['Profit'].values)
plt.show()
```

Note that you could use the `plot` method on your dataframe as:

```
ax = raw_data.plot('Profit')
plt.show()
```